# XPath for XML tag depending on position in text?

Tags: xml, xpath

I am looking for XPath expressions that will differentiate between two scenarios involving the same tag.

**Scenario 1:**
`<include.text>` comes in the middle of a string, for example:

`<par>We are certain that <include.text><Reference/></include.text> will be a big hit.</par>`

**Scenario 2:**
`<include.text>` comes directly after another (arbitrary) tag, for example:

`<par><include.text><Reference/></include.text> will be a big hit.</par>`

As far as I'm concerned, I can use `//include.text` for the first scenario, but I need another Xpath expression that will allow me to differentiate the scenarios where it comes directly after an opening tag (`par` in this case, but it could be anything). Generally the opening tag (`par`) will be a parent and not a sibling. I've looked into `ends-with()`, etc. but I'm not that good at XPath yet.

Comment: What does "differentiate" mean to you? What element you want to **select**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this XML,

```
<r>
  <par>We are certain that <include.text><Reference/></include.text> will be a big hit.</par>
  <par><include.text><Reference/></include.text> will be a big hit.</par>
</r>
```

this XPath,

```
//include.text[not(preceding-sibling::node())]
```

will select only the second `include.text` because it has no preceding sibling nodes.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!!